# Finding number of possible sequences in an array, with additional conditions

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

There is a sequence {a1, a2, a3, a4, ..... aN}. A run is the maximal strictly increasing or strictly decreasing continuous part of the sequence. Eg. If we have a sequence {1,2,3,4,7,6,5,2,3,4,1,2} We have 5 possible runs {1,2,3,4,7}, {7,6,5,2}, {2,3,4}, {4,1} and {1,2}.

Given four numbers N, M, K, L. Count the number of possible sequences of N numbers that has exactly M runs, each of the number in the sequence is less than or equal to K and difference between the adjacent numbers is less than equal to L

The question was asked during an interview.

I could only think of a brute force solution. **What is an efficient solution for this problem?**

Comment: It is a nice question Peter, but please try to be more informative in the title of the question, and leave non-important details to the question itself. I editted the question for you now - please read it and make sure I didn't miss anything you find important.

Comment: @hamstergene it was not mentioned in the place i saw this question

Comment: I think you're missing a detail, such as each number in the sequence is nonnegative.  Otherwise the restriction that "each of the number in the sequence is less than or equal to K" doesn't do much - your values could still range all the way to negative infinity.

Comment: ok lets assume all nos in sequence are distinct and non negative

Comment: Not sure if you want to assume that they are all distinct - that might change the solution.

Comment: ...mainly considering that in the OP's examples there are duplicates indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic programming. For each number in the substring maintain separate count of maximal increasing and maximally decreasing subsequences. When you incrementally add a new number to the end you can use these counts to update the counts for the new number. Complexity: O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

This can be rephrased as a recurrence problem.  Look at your problem as finding #(N, M) (assume K and L are fixed, they are used in the recurrence conditions, so propagate accordingly).  Now start with the more restricted count functions A(N, M; a) and D(N, M, a), where A counts those sets with last run ascending, D counts those with last run descending, and a is the value of the last element in the set.

Express #(N, M) in terms of A(N, M; a) and D(N, M; a) (it's the sum over all allowable a).  You might note that there are relations between the two (like the reflection A(N, M; a) = D(N, M; K-a)) but that won't matter much for the calculation except to speed table filling.

Now A(N, M; a) can be expressed in terms of A(N-1, M; w), A(N-1, M-1; x), D(N-1, M; y) and D(N-1, M-1; z).  The idea is that if you start with a set of size N-1 and know the direction of the last run and the value of the last element, you know whether adding element a will add to an existing run or add a run.  So you can count the number of possible ways to get what you want from the possibilities of the previous case.

I'll let you write this recursion down.  Note that this is where you account for L (only add up those that obey the L distance restriction) and K (look for end cases).

Terminate the recursion using the fact that A(1, 1; a) = 1, A(1, x>1; a) = 0 (and similarly for D).

Now, since this is a multiple recursion, be sure your implementation stores results in a table and begins by trying lookup (commonly called dynamic programming).

Comment: Sorry, switched notation halfway through.  I'll fix.

Comment: And to be explicit about the complexity, note that a brute force count is O(K^N), whereas this is O(LN).

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you mean by 'brute force solution' what I might mean by 'straightforward solution involving nested-loops over N,M,K,L' ?  Sometimes the straightforward solution is good enough.  One of the times when the straightforward solution is good enough is when you don't have a better solution.  Another of the times is when the numbers are not very large.

With that off my chest I would write the loops in the reverse direction, or something like that.  I mean:

1. Create 2 auxiliary data structures, one to contain the indices of the numbers <=K, one for the indices of the numbers whose difference with their neighbours is <=L.
2. Run through the list of numbers and populate the foregoing auxiliary data structures.
3. Find the intersection of the values in those 2 data structures; these will be the indices of interesting places to start searching for runs.
4. Look in each of the interesting places.

Until someone demonstrates otherwise this is the most efficient solution.

Comment: What is the complexity of this solution?

Comment: Quite, I mean 'quite complex'.

Comment: Kind of hard to judge that your solution is more efficient than anything else.

Comment: @mbeckish: I only judge that my solution is more efficient than any other solution that has been posted yet.  I will happily yield my (self-donned) laurels when you, or someone else, posts a more efficient solution.

Comment: "I will happily yield my (self-donned) laurels when you, or someone else, posts a more efficient solution."  Do you mean "or someone else, posts any solution and states the complexity of the solution" since we don't know the complexity of your solution?

Comment: Yeah, something like that.  But I see that someone has already snatched off my laurels.  I am woebegone.